# Can't show two layers one above another in RMMapView from Mapbox SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I have two URL templates (one is a terrain and another is labels). So I need to show the label layer (which is transparent with layers) above the map tiles.

I inherited from `RMAbstractWebMapSource` and made a class `AxMapKitTileSource` where override a method of providing URL template.

So, that's how I initialize `RMMapView`. I have a class, in witch I firstly made the initializing like this:

```
- (void) commonInitializer
{
    self.mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];

    self.mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self addSubview:self.mapView];
    [self updateTiledLayer: self.tiledLayerMode];
}
```

And in this method I add the tiles to the mapView:

```
- (void) updateTiledLayer:(AxMapTiledLayerMode)layerMode
{
    [self.mapView removeTileSource:self.mapView.tileSource];

    [self.mapView removeTileSource:self.mainTileSourse];
    [self.mapView removeTileSource:self.auxTileSourse];

    [self.mapView removeAllCachedImages];

    self.mainTileSourse = nil;
    self.auxTileSourse = nil;

    NSString *mainTemplateURL = [[AxMapKitConfiguration sharedInstance] URLTemplateForMainTiledLayerForMode:layerMode];
    NSInteger mainLayerZoomCorrection = [[AxMapKitConfiguration sharedInstance] zoomOffsetForMainTiledLayerForMode:layerMode];

    if (mainTemplateURL && mainTemplateURL.length > 0) {
        self.mainTileSourse = [[AxMapKitTileSource alloc] initWithURLTemplate:mainTemplateURL withZoomCorrection:mainLayerZoomCorrection];

        [self.mapView setTileSource:self.mainTileSourse];
    }

    NSString *auxTemplateURL = [[AxMapKitConfiguration sharedInstance] URLTemplateForAuxTiledLayerForMode:layerMode];
    NSInteger auxLayerZoomCorrection = [[AxMapKitConfiguration sharedInstance] zoomOffsetForAuxTiledLayerForMode:layerMode];

    if (auxTemplateURL && auxTemplateURL.length > 0) {
        self.auxTileSourse = [[AxMapKitTileSource alloc] initWithURLTemplate:auxTemplateURL withZoomCorrection:auxLayerZoomCorrection];

        [self.mapView addTileSource:self.auxTileSourse];
    }
}
```

As I see from the docs `addTileSource:` should add the layer above the current layers, but the second layer is not appearing on the mapView. I think, I have some initialization issue here - do you help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage looks right. One thing you might want to look at if you are not expecting to toggle the visibility of either layer is `RMCompositeSource`, which will fetch in parallel and client-side composite the layers, caching the result, and is a more efficient way to show layers that are always visible.